# Customizing Multiple Choice Questions in EqExam Package

Tags: formatting

I use `eqexam` for creating Multiple Choice Questions with randomized answers. Let's take the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[allowrandomize,nopoints,proofing]{eqexam}%

\begin{document}

\useRandomSeed{2012}
\begin{exam}{Exam1}
\begin{problem}
In what year did Columbus sail the ocean blue?
\begin{answers}{2}
    \bChoices[random]
    \Ans0 1st random choice\eAns
    \Ans1\label{eq} 2nd (the correct) random choice\eAns
    \Ans0 3rd random choice\eAns
    \Ans0 4th random choice\eAns
    \Ans0 5th random chioce\eAns
    \eFreeze
    \Ans0 None of these\eAns
    \eChoices
\end{answers}
\end{problem}
\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:
[image: PDF output]

I want to be able to customize the `problem` and `answers` environments, more exactly, to put the problem number inside a `\fbox` and change the text size, and also the way the choices are numbered - I want to put capital letters A, B, C, ... inside `\fbox`, but I don't know how this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\usepackage[pointsonleft,showgrayletters,
nototals,forpaper,nosolutions,useforms,usexkv]{eqexam}
```

and put

```
\def\exlabelformat{\fbox{\textbf{\theeqquestionnoi.}}\ }
```

in your preamble.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks), as I did in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Indeed, using `showgrayletters`, `forpaper` and `useforms` options does part of the trick, the other options seem not to be relevant to my case. Also, redefining `\exlabelformat` seems to help.